# SAPUI5 - How to search formatted date from table

Tags: sapui5

I have a date column with format MMM d, yyyy. If user searches "2018", how can I filter it?

XML

```
<table:Column filterProperty="StartDate" sortProperty="StartDate" width="100px" tooltip="{i18n>ttStartDate}">
    <Label text="Start Date"/>
    <table:template>
    <Text text="{path:'localModel>StartDate',formatter:'.formatter.date'}"/>
        </table:template>
</table:Column>
```

Controller

```
searchTable: function (evt) {
            var oTable = this.getView().byId("ordersTable");
            var searchTerm = evt.getParameter("query");
            if (searchTerm === "") {
                //When clear was pressed on search field
                oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(null);
            } else {
                var filters = [];
                var outerFilters = [];
                var searchTerms = searchTerm.split(" "); //words separated by space are considered as separate search terms. 
                for (var k = 0; k < searchTerms.length; k++) {

                    filters.push(new Filter("OrderType", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchTerms[k]));
                    filters.push(new Filter("StartDate", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchTerms[k]));
                    outerFilters.push(new Filter(filters));
                    filters = [];
                }
                oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(new Filter({
                    filters: outerFilters,
                    and: true //Default is OR between filters
                }));
            }
        },
```

Date received as : **StartDate: Sat Mar 23 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530**
Date formatted as: **Mar 23,2019**

I am aware that 'Contains' works only for Strings but how to make it work for date also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We faced a similar issue and there were 2 solutions,
One on the client side and another on the server side.

Client side:
Use a formatter on that property to parse the date to a string.

Server side:
Ask for another property that is that date as a string.

Looking at your code I can see you are already using a formatter (*formatter.date*) so we can explore the client side option.

In your formater.date function you can do something like this:

```
date(yourDateField)
{
   let options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
   return yourDateField.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But for filter I have used date from model (StartDate). So it was not working initially. I have added below code

filters.push(new Filter({
                        path: "",
                        test: function(value){ 
                            var formatted = formatter.date(value.StartDate);
                                return formatted.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
                        }
                    }));
This worked. But it takes some time (2 seconds) to load. Is there any better option to handle this?